# Check Which Website is Visited

Tags: c++, url, process, web

I've been having trouble finding a way to check if the user of the program is visiting a specific website. If I wanted to open a pop up box telling me which website I was currently on, what would be the best way to do it?

I've been thinking about various ways but I can never come to a definite conclusion. Thought about checking which browser is open by browsing the processes or checking the window, but how would I find it out? Even if I didn't find out exact website address but just the name, would be fine.

For example, right now the window open says 'Check Which Website is Visited - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox', is there a way to get that from a programming standpoint? Like somehow check and read what windows are currently open.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I doubt there is a real answer to this. The user could have multiple web browsers installed, so a window-based search can fail. A single web page can (often will) have pieces from multiple servers so tracking URLs or IP addresses is also likely to fail.

Comment: Well there are programs that do this, so I was just wondering how it's possible. Is there a way to access the list of applications running that you see from the taskmgr? If so, you could search, because if it's a browser, it'll say the browser name in the application name, ex: "Google - Mozilla" or "Google - Chrome".

Comment: I believe the applications Windows shows in the task manager come from using `EnumWindows` to enumerate top-level windows. If finding instances of the half dozen (of so) main browsers is enough, that'll probably work reasonably well.

Comment: I had deleted my original answer but then decided to just update it and undelete - I'm having a very indecisive kinda day. Doing what you want is going to be either problematic or very specific to each browser. In the past I've used browser plugins and IPC to do this but even then it's a lot of effort. I've included some basic information to push you in the right direction but in the end you may find that the effort to do such a thing is not worth the overall rewards.

Comment: well what if we assumed they were only using mozilla or chrome or internet explorer? That shouldn't be so hard should it, because regardless of the version, the window will still just be titled either mozilla firefox or chrome, or IE

Answer (score 2):

To get the title of the active window use this code:

```
HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
CString title;
LPTSTR str = title.GetBufferSetLength(GetWindowTextLength(hwnd));
GetWindowText(hwnd, str, title.GetLength() + 1);
if (title.IsEmpty())title = _T("User Desktop");
...
```

The active window will be under "title".

To get the active running application use this code:

```
    DWORD pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), &pid);
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
if (hProcess != NULL)
{
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    TCHAR filename[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, path, MAX_PATH);
    _wsplitpath(path, NULL, NULL, filename, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
...
```

filename will hold the active application

Comment: I tested and this page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  (for example) appears in my program's log as:
"Active Window 'EnumWindows function (Windows) - Google Chrome'" and I would like to know how can I capture the address of the page as well.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the exact URL of the current site from a web browser is going to be specific to each browser. In most cases the easiest way is going to be creating a browser plugin or extension that your application can communicate with to retrieve the desired information. Whether that is a viable option or not is going to be specific to what you are trying to do and whether the user is willing to install the plugin. A lot of applications such as Yahoo Messenger used to do this to integrate messenger functionality into the browser but I don't know if they still do.

Even retrieving just the title is going to be problematic as each browser is different. In some cases you can use [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the caption bar title. Unfortunately browsers such as Internet Explorer and Chrome use tabs or custom embedded controls to present that information to users so using `GetWindowText` is of limited use in this case.

In order to use [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve the text in the caption bar you will have to obtain the handle to the specific web browser window though. You can do this with [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use information like [process ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with that owns the window or the [window class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (not a C++ class) to determine if it's a browser window. You will also need to deal with the possibility that there could be more than own browser window open. In this case you could prompt the user with a list of titles and have them select one, it just depends on what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is there not a way to get the current selected window? Like, I'm on stackoverlow flow, even tho I have chrome open with Google.

Comment: When using `EnumWindows` the windows are enumerated by z-order so the first one you find will be the top most browser window and the last one will be the bottom  most.