# How can I grab the contents of a browsers address bar in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I need to grab the content of the active windows address bar if it is a web browser in c++.  I have figured out how to grab the title, and can grab the contents of notepad, but I am getting stuck on the browsers.

My goal is to have this work for IE, Chrome, and Firefox.  If this requires different methods I would have the program try each one until one returns data.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
    HWND hwndEdit = FindWindowEx(foreground, NULL, "EDIT", NULL);

    const int bufferSize = 5024;
    char textBuffer[bufferSize] = "";
    SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)bufferSize, (LPARAM)textBuffer);

    cout << textBuffer;
```

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but it all depends on the browser. Internet Explorer is quite easy, for it is indeed edit box (well it was for sure, but could be changed.) FireFox, however, has its own way to displaying it, and when I was working a long time on an (unfinished) project like that we were unable to get it by simply finding a window. FireFox, however, had a special set of functions to obtain contents of the address bar (don't remember that.) I hope you will get good answers which I can also use in a future. Good luck!

Comment: @Grzegorz I had a feeling that would be the case, I just need something to point me int he right direction so I can find the method for each common browser.

Comment: I should point out at this time it does not work for any of the browsers I listed.

Comment: When we were trying to locate proper address bar control, we were using Visual Studio, and there was a tool there that was allowing to hover the mouse over, and show control windows handles, types, and names. I don't remember about FireFox, unfortunately. It was like 4 years ago. Sorry!

Comment: @Grzegorz That would probably be Spy++ (Not found in VS express, but google WinSpy++). Thing is modern browsers probably use custom controls for address bars, but worth a try.

Comment: @user2802841 Bingo! That's the name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like I have this working for IE, still working on FireFox and Chrome.

Here is the code for IE

```
    HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
    HWND hwndEdit = FindWindowEx(foreground, NULL, "EDIT", NULL);

    HWND handle = FindWindowEx(foreground, NULL, "WorkerW", "Navigation Bar");
    if (NULL != handle)
    {
    handle = FindWindowEx(handle, NULL, "ReBarWindow32", NULL);
    if (NULL != handle)
    {
    handle = FindWindowEx(handle, NULL, "Address Band Root", NULL);
    }}
    HWND hwndEdit = FindWindowEx(handle, NULL, "Edit", NULL);

    const int bufferSize = 5024;
    Char textBuffer[bufferSize] = "";
    SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)bufferSize, (LPARAM)textBuffer);

    string addressbartext = textBuffer;
    if(addressbartext == "AutoCompleteProxy")
    {addressbartext = "";}
    else
    {addressbartext = textBuffer;
    }

    cout << addressbartext;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another working method working for IE instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Exdisp.h>

//This imports the shell extionsions
//we disable warnings of multiple defines
#pragma warning(disable: 4192)
#pragma warning(disable: 4146)
#import <mshtml.tlb>
#import <shdocvw.dll>

void PrintBrowserInfo(IWebBrowser2 *pBrowser) {
    //These functions return Unicode strings.
    BSTR bstr;
    //Get the window title
    pBrowser->get_LocationName(&bstr);
    wprintf(L"Title: %s\n", bstr);
    SysFreeString(bstr);
    //Detect if this is Windows Explorer (My Computer) or Internet Explorer (the internet)
    IDispatchPtr spDisp;
    char *type = "Windows Explorer";
    if (pBrowser->get_Document(&spDisp) == S_OK && spDisp != NULL) {
        MSHTML::IHTMLDocument2Ptr spHtmlDocument(spDisp);
        if (spHtmlDocument != NULL) {
            MSHTML::IHTMLElementPtr spHtmlElement;
            spHtmlDocument->get_body(&spHtmlElement);
            if (spHtmlElement != NULL) {
                type = "Internet Explorer";
            }
        }
        spDisp.Release();
    }
    printf(" Type: %s\n", type);
    //Get the URL of the folder or web page
    pBrowser->get_LocationURL(&bstr);
    wprintf(L"  URL: %s\n\n", bstr);
    SysFreeString(bstr);
}

int main() {
    CoInitialize(NULL); //We need COM
    SHDocVw::IShellWindowsPtr spSHWinds;
    IDispatchPtr spDisp;
    //Find all explorer (Windows and Internet) and list them
    if (spSHWinds.CreateInstance(__uuidof(SHDocVw::ShellWindows)) == S_OK) {
        long nCount = spSHWinds->GetCount();
        for (long i = 0; i < nCount; i++) {
            _variant_t va(i, VT_I4);
            spDisp = spSHWinds->Item(va);
            SHDocVw::IWebBrowser2Ptr spBrowser(spDisp);
            if (spBrowser != NULL) {
                //spBrowser->AddRef();
                PrintBrowserInfo((IWebBrowser2 *)spBrowser.GetInterfacePtr());
                spBrowser.Release();
            }
        }
    } else {
        puts("Shell windows failed to initialise");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [Check Which Website is Visited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254798/check-which-website-is-visited/30479840?sfb=2#30479840) but let me know you if find a better solution, especially for Chrome.